# Get clipboard's content from microsoft office format with Apache Tika

Tags: java, apache-tika

Is it possible to get clipboard's content from microsoft office format with Apache Tika?
How can I achieve it?

Comment: Do you want to get the contents of the Clipboard, or have you already fetched it somehow and now want to parse it?